# Script Returning Strings of Inconsistent Length

Tags: javascript, recursion

The intention of this script is to print 8 "blocks" of randomly generated alphanumeric values separated by dashes to make a unique ID of 39 characters.

> E7L9-XNP4-UB4K-10PU-H8IZ-C69E-3IG2-6P6W

However, I find that this script will sometimes return strings less than 39 characters with blocks that contain only 2 or 3 characters.

> 21-15-18-5UD1-V471-I158-J23R-M714

I tried putting a condition that would run blockBuilder() recursively if the resulting block was less than 4 characters yet those defective IDs would still be printed to the page.

```js
var alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z";

var alphaArray = alphabet.split(",").map(function(l) {
  return l.toUpperCase()
});

function randomLetter() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  return alphaArray[index];
}

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

function blockBuilder() {
  var block = randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar();

  if (block.length < 4) {
    blockBuilder(); //recursive check
  }

  return block;
}

function idBuilder() {
  return blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder()


}

function randomChar() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? randomLetter() : randomNumber();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var v = idBuilder();

  document.write(v + "<br>");

}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: try 'if (block.length < 4) { block = blockBuilder(); }'

Comment: @Aaron: But `block.length` should never be `< 4`, the check is pointless.

Comment: Your recursive call isn't actually adding to the blocks variable.

Comment: I believe this happens when you get two `0` out of `randomNumber`, try casting the chars to string by `String(randomChar())`

Comment: @JuanStiza: Doesn't even have to be 0. If the leading calls to `randomChar` in `blockBuilder` go to `randomNumber`, the results will be added. So for instance, `2 + 3 + 4 + "X"` ends up as `"9X"`, not `"234X"`. `6 + 1 + "A" + 3` ends up being `"7A3"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ha! you are right! Your solution covers it all then.

Comment: Instead of separate `randomLetter` and `randomNumber` functions, why don't you just add digits to your `alphabet` string?

Comment: @Barmar: Seems to want to use digits half the time, letters half the time, based on the implementation of `randomChar`. (As opposed to digits 10:36 of the time and letters 26:36 of the time.) Not saying I agree that's a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your `randomNumber` function returns a **number**, not a digit. If you have two in a row, they're added together, not concatenated. For instance, in this line:

```
var block = randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar();
```

...suppose the first call returns 2, the second returns 3, the third returns 4, and the fourth returns `"X"`. That's:

```
var block = 2 + 3 + 4 + "X";
```

...which is `"9X"`, not `"234X"`. This will happen any time the first and second calls (at least) return numbers.

Converting to string solves it:

```
function randomNumber() {
  return String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}
```

Example:

```js
var alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z";

var alphaArray = alphabet.split(",").map(function(l) {
  return l.toUpperCase()
});

function randomLetter() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  return alphaArray[index];
}

function randomNumber() {
  return String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}

function blockBuilder() {
  var block = randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar();

  if (block.length < 4) {
    blockBuilder(); //recursive check
  }

  return block;
}

function idBuilder() {
  return blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder()


}

function randomChar() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? randomLetter() : randomNumber()
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var v = idBuilder();

  document.write(v + "<br>");

}
```

---

Side note: The `if (block.length < 4)` is unnecessary, with the check it cannot be true. (Just calling `blockBuilder` again without doing anything with its result wouldn't have helped anyway.)

Side note 2: Your `randomChar` function picks either a letter or a number (digit), giving each a 50/50 chance. That reduces the uniqueness of your strings, by limiting to only 10 choices half the time. You might consider doing what [Barmar asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277653/script-returning-strings-of-inconsistent-length?noredirect=1#comment87573626_50277653) and just adding the digits to your overall list, which would A) Make the implementation simpler, and B) Spread things more evenly amongst the 36 choices.

For instance:

```js
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split("");

function blockBuilder() {
  var block = randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar() + randomChar();
  return block;
}

function idBuilder() {
  return blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder() + "-" + blockBuilder()
}

function randomChar() {
  return chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var v = idBuilder();
  document.write(v + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: I think it always happen if you're calling randomNumber() twice, regardless of its result being 0 or something else, because the two numbers are then added and result in a single number (e.g. 2 + 2 results in 4, not in 22).

Comment: @Ridcully: Quite true. My example even shows that, but you're right that my mentioning the 0 was misleading. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance it seems to me that sometimes you will get only numbers thus javascript engine will convert it somewhere in between into number like `2+1+2+9 => 14` instead of `2129`, try something like this in place of `randomChar()` function and you wouldn't even need to check the length: `return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? randomLetter() : randomNumber().toString();`

Comment: Dang it, you just beat me.  Yep.  Numbers add together, if it's over 10, you won't notice it happened, if under 10, then it drops a character.  That's why all 3 letter blocks start with a number